# Removing HyperLinks from search result content (Solr 3.4.0)

Tags: search, filter, hyperlink, solr

I'm working on Solr project.. When I search for a word say (google) ,the results will be something like this:

---

Google

[Sign In] [About us] google is a search engine.... etc

www.google.com

---

As you can see, in the search results I need to remove the Hyperlinks (About us and Sign in ) from the content.. How can I do this with Solr.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr would return you back what you feed into Solr.
So if the link are stored into the field, they would be returned with the response as is.
The filtering part needs to be handled at client side.

Comment: Or do the filtering on the process that is inserting the items into the index.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra and Paige Cook for your answers, I would like to ask if I use an analyzer for the query in my Schema.xml can I add a specific filter to remove the [link] ??

Comment: The Analysers and filters worked only on the data indexed. So a filter like HTMLFilter would remove the html tags in your indexed data. However, the stored data is not modified and would remain as is fed to solr. So the handling has to be done before the data is fed or at the client side, before the data is displayed.